# Deserialise POJO array member from its string representation

Tags: java, spring, jackson, lombok

I am looking for a generic way to deserialise with Jackson a JSON such as:

```
{
    "hello": "baby",
    "eyes": "[blue,green]"
}
```

To a POJO such as

```
public class Whatever {
    @Setter private String hello;
    @Setter private List<Color> eyes;
}
```

With Color being an enum.

When I try naively like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.convertValue(properties, objectClass);
```

I get the error

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

Obviously this is because Jackson can only deserialise arrays from JSON arrays, not their string representation.

I tried to activate ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY but it would consider the value of the property "eyes" to be an array with a single String element "[blue,green]" (which fails to convert to the enumeration Color)

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY is causing the "eyes" property to be interpreted as an array with a single element, that option allows Jackson to coerce types so that

```
{
  "hello": "baby",
  "eyes": "[blue,green]"
}
```

would be interpreted the same as

```
[{
  "hello": "baby",
  "eyes": "[blue,green]"
}]
```

This way single elements can be used with Java's Collections more information can be found at

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY

As far as your problem goes, the best option would be to have the JSON submitted with color as a JSON array like:

```
{
  "hello": "baby",
  "eyes": [
    "blue",
    "green",
  ]
}
```

Otherwise you may need to have your `Whatever` class have the `@JsonSetter` annotation on a `setEyes` method with String parameter where you parse the String to manually create the list of `Color` yourself.

```
@JsonSetter
public void setEyes(final String eyes) {
    // Parse string and set field here
}
```

Comment: After investigation, it looks like it can't be helped as you suggested. So I ended up implementing my own system. Thank you for the hints !